# Can A/an go with noun1 and noun 2 Or A/an must always go with adj + noun?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, sentence-structure, pronouns

Example:He is old enough to live an (depend) life,can someone explain me why can't i use indepence instead of independent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking why you can write

> He is old enough to live an independen**t** life.

, but not

> He is old enough to live an independen**ce** life.

, it is because nouns like `independence` cannot be used to modify other nouns. Instead, adjectives like `independent` can modify nouns.

> #### [Adjective](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/adjective)
>
> ...typically [serves] as a modifier of a noun to denote a quality of the thing named...

---

> #### [Noun](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/noun)
>
> ...can [...] serve as the subject of a verb [...], and refer to an entity, quality, state, action, or concept...

Thus, both nouns and adjectives **can** refer to qualities or properties, but only the adjective that refers to a chosen property can be used to modify the noun that possesses the property.

#### X of Y

Nonetheless, one noun could be 'of' another, such as

> He is old enough to live a life **of** independence.

, meaning that the `life` in question has the quality or property of independence (or if you will, of being independent). This can sometimes be used to create rather elegant sentences.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any situation where you would have two nouns next to each other unless they formed a compound noun. Some compound nouns consist of an adjective and a noun, but when they consist of two nouns there is no space in between them.

[Learn English Grammar - Compound Nouns](https://www.learnenglish.de/grammar/nouncompound.html)

'Independencelife' is not a word in English and I wouldn't even call 'independent life' a compound noun. This is a pretty clear case of the noun 'life' being modified by the adjective 'independent'. The only way you can write it correctly is 'independent life'.